# Print Page Break Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, css, bootstrap-4

I have a payslip that is generated using Bootstrap via PHP. I need to make a new page every 6 payslips.

Here is my code to generate the payslips.

```
foreach($results as $result){
    foreach($result as $fetchall){
         if($counter % 6 == 0){
            $pgbreak = 'pgbreak';
         }
         else{
            $pgbreak = '';
         }

         $payslip .= '<div class="col-sm-4 '. $pgbreak .'">';
         $counter++;

         $payslip .= '<div class="payslip-title"></div>';
                         
         $payslip .= '</div>';
   }
}
```

Here is my CSS code where I put my page break:

```
@media print { div.pgbreak { page-break-after: always;} }
```

Here is the sample output

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCLiB.png)

Answer (score 0):

For page breaking, you can look at :

- `page-break-before`
- `page-break-inside`
- `page-break-after`

When I want to export datas into a `.pdf` for printing, I usually use [html2pdf](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf).
The templating isn't easy and all `css` properties aren't interpreted, but when done you're sure of the result.

---

Edit :

You need to add a `page-break-after: always;` each 4 items.

```
$payslip .= '<div class="col-sm-6">';
```

Become :

```
$payslip .= '<div class="col-sm-6 payslip-item">';
```

And add the following CSS :

```
.payslip-item:nth-child(4n) {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

PS : i've not tested this

---

Edit 2 :

Ho i've forget, `page-break-inside` is replaced by `break-inside`.
Also, few tests later, selected element need to have `display: block;` (doesn't word on `display: inline-block` with Chrome)...

---

Here is a working example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
        .page {
            page-break-inside: avoid;
            page-break-after: always;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <?php
        $closed = true;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 40; $i++) {
            if ($i % 6 == 0) {
                echo '<div class="row page">';
                $closed = false;
            }
        ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4 item">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <?php
            if ($i % 6 == 5) {
                echo '</div>';
                $closed = true;
            }
        }
        if (!$closed) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the problem is I dont know where to put the page break in my php code

Comment: Can you show the full code? I cant seem to make it work

Comment: I can't, I'm live testing on website i've done at work... I've no minimal code to show sorry.

Comment: But do a minimal reproductive code, and I'ill update it to show you.

Comment: just tell me what part of my code do i need to put the page break

Comment: A solution is to create a div containing your 4 payslips, and put `page-break: avoid; page-break-after: always;` on it.